# Basic typeahead implementation

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am trying to implement the countries typeahead example, but am having difficulty getting it to load. What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EXgq9/

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" placeholder="Enter your location">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'countries',
    prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json',
    limit: 10
  });
}
```

Comment: Is your `prefetch` parameter specifying a different domain to that of the page where you use that code? Note that your fiddle didn't work at all because you didn't select "jQuery" from the "Frameworks & Extensions" drop-down, and didn't specify to include the typeahead plugin, but even if you fix that it still won't work because of a URL that won't resolve to an accessible path.

Comment: That was just my attempt to use jsfiddle and provide you guys with some code (I added typeahead.js as an external resource); the prefetch sits on my server.

Comment: There are a bunch of issues with your jsfiddle. Your external resources are pointing to bad URLs, you have a syntax error, and your prefetch url will 404. Without fixing that, it's almost impossible to help debug your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the nearly working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GDqme/

The problem with your code is you are attempting to use:

```
prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json'
```

And it doesn't work since it would be cross site request and Twitter doesn't allow that.

What you should do is download that JSON file and set it up locally:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'countries',
    prefetch: '/data/countries.json',
    limit: 10
});
```

Anyway, remember that the `console` (from Firebug / Chrome dev tools) is your friend.